# PHP: How to delete a page after 24 hours?

Tags: php, delay, sleep

We'd like to have PHP automatically delete a page from our website 24 hours after a specified date and time. The purpose is to offer promotional coupons to certain customers that last only 24 hours. How can we do this? (I'm ultra novice so please answer by example  code rather than explanation. Thank you.)

What we have so far:

```
<?php
$filename = "myfile.txt";
sleep (86400);
unlink($filename);
?>
```

This doesn't make sense though because I think the page has to be open for a full 24 hours (86,400 seconds) for it to execute, yes? Also, the 24 hours countdown should start at a specified date and time. What code would do this?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

Don't delete it... just don't show it.  I'd avoid using PHP via web to delete stuff on local system.  Basically, wrap the code in an include where if with the date range show, otherwise don't.

Better yet, store the offer details in a CSV file, XML doc, or database with start & finish date/times and use that for your check.

Comment: +1:  Agreed.  Also, the 24 hour timer would have to be started at the right time, and could not be interrupted until expiration, like rebooting for maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want things to happen at scheduled times as opposed to responses to user events, use they scheduling system built into the operating system. On Linux/Unix, that would be cron.

It is too detailed to explain here but it isn't terrible complicated. Just BE CAREFUL if you are deleting files.

Wikipedia has a good overview of cron here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Of course, using cron usually requires that you have terminal access to the server.